# How do I make the JS Code in the Devtools Chrome Sorted?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I was in the Devtools while I stumbled upon a JS code which I clearly could not read. Does anybody know how I can enable sorting of the code?
I tried to Search on Google "How to Sort the JS-Code in Chrome devtools making it viewable" but found nothing.

[image: Image of Devtools not sorted]

Comment: I also tried to refresh the Page, but it still is this Block of mess. and on Google.com it is even bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, pressing this button should prettify it.

[image: Button]

Comment: oh i never saw this, but thank you kind Stranger.